# how to automate desktop application authorization process?

Tags: java, testing, exe, desktop-application

I have this application exe
[image]

And I have a file with a user name and password. how can I do so that the application to be started when he was authorized?
how this can be done without the use of clickers, bots, etc?
the means by which this can be done?
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

You should able to accomplish this using vbScript.